# Is the set of continuous, monotonic functions on $[0, 1]$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization, convex-optimization

I'm looking at an optimisation problem, where we want to optimise over continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. I would like to know, whether, within this space, the subset of monotonically increasing functions is convex or not.

Comment: The codomain of the functions is $\mathbb R$? And monotic allows both increasing and decreasing?

Comment: @PaulFrost thank you for pointing that out, I've edited the question.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich no, I didn't - it says in the question, that I am asking about monotonically increasing functions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ be monotonely increasing functions mapping $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda,x,y\in[0,1]$ be arbitrary, with $x<y$.
Then,
$$
\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)g(x)\leq \lambda f(y)+(1-\lambda)g(y)
$$
So, $\lambda f+(1-\lambda)g$ is also a montonely increasing function.